# OperationalError when querying

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, operationalerror

I am trying to populate my database with puppypopulator.py provided in the lesson. But the problem that I am facing is when I am querying it against a session in the shell to check if I have correctly populated my database I find this error:-

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more in                                                              formation.
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
>>> from database_setup_puppy import Base, Puppy, Shelter
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///puppies.db
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    engine = create_engine('sqlite:///puppies.db
                                               ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> engine = create_engine('sqlite:///puppies.db')
>>> Base.metadata.bind = engine
>>> DBSession = sessionmaker(bind = engine)
>>> session = DBSession()
>>> session.query(Puppy).all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/or                                                              m/query.py", line 2703, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/or                                                              m/query.py", line 2855, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/or                                                              m/query.py", line 2878, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._para                                                              ms)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sq                                                              l/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multipara                                                              ms, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ut                                                              il/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cau                                                              se)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError)                                                               no such column: puppy.dateOfBirth [SQL: u'SELECT puppy.id AS                                                               puppy_id, puppy.name AS puppy_name, puppy.gender AS puppy_g                                                              ender, puppy."dateOfBirth" AS "puppy_dateOfBirth", puppy.pic                                                              ture AS puppy_picture, puppy.shelter_id AS puppy_shelter_id,                                                               puppy.weight AS puppy_weight \nFROM puppy']
>>> session.query(Shelter).all()
[]
>>> session.query(Puppy).all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/or                                                              m/query.py", line 2703, in all
    return list(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/or                                                              m/query.py", line 2855, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/or                                                              m/query.py", line 2878, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._para                                                              ms)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sq                                                              l/elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multipara                                                              ms, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/ut                                                              il/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cau                                                              se)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/en                                                              gine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError)                                                               no such column: puppy.dateOfBirth [SQL: u'SELECT puppy.id AS                                                               puppy_id, puppy.name AS puppy_name, puppy.gender AS puppy_g                                                              ender, puppy."dateOfBirth" AS "puppy_dateOfBirth", puppy.pic                                                              ture AS puppy_picture, puppy.shelter_id AS puppy_shelter_id,                                                               puppy.weight AS puppy_weight \nFROM puppy']
>>>
```

My Code for database_setup_puppy.py as used in the above shell import is this :-

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, Date, Numeric
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

Base = declarative_base()

class Shelter(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'shelter'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name =Column(String(80), nullable = False)
    address = Column(String(250))
    city = Column(String(80))
    state = Column(String(20))
    zipCode = Column(String(10))
    website = Column(String)

class Puppy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'puppy'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    gender = Column(String(6), nullable = False)
    dateOfBirth = Column(Date)
    picture = Column(String)
    shelter_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('shelter.id'))
    shelter = relationship(Shelter)
    weight = Column(Numeric(10))
```

And the puppy populator module is this :-

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
 
from puppies import Base, Shelter, Puppy
#from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from random import randint
import datetime
import random


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///puppyshelter.db')

Base.metadata.bind = engine
 
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

session = DBSession()


#Add Shelters
shelter1 = Shelter(name = "Oakland Animal Services", address = "1101 29th Ave", city = "Oakland", state = "California", zipCode = "94601", website = "oaklandanimalservices.org")
session.add(shelter1)

shelter2 = Shelter(name = "San Francisco SPCA Mission Adoption Center", address="250 Florida St", city="San Francisco", state="California", zipCode = "94103", website = "sfspca.org")
session.add(shelter2)

shelter3 = Shelter(name = "Wonder Dog Rescue", address= "2926 16th Street", city = "San Francisco", state = "California" , zipCode = "94103", website = "http://wonderdogrescue.org")
session.add(shelter3)

shelter4 = Shelter(name = "Humane Society of Alameda", address = "PO Box 1571" ,city = "Alameda" ,state = "California", zipCode = "94501", website = "hsalameda.org")
session.add(shelter4)

shelter5 = Shelter(name = "Palo Alto Humane Society" ,address = "1149 Chestnut St." ,city = "Menlo Park", state = "California" ,zipCode = "94025", website = "paloaltohumane.org")
session.add(shelter5)


#Add Puppies

male_names = ["Bailey", "Max", "Charlie", "Buddy","Rocky","Jake", "Jack", "Toby", "Cody", "Buster", "Duke", "Cooper", "Riley", "Harley", "Bear", "Tucker", "Murphy", "Lucky", "Oliver", "Sam", "Oscar", "Teddy", "Winston", "Sammy", "Rusty", "Shadow", "Gizmo", "Bentley", "Zeus", "Jackson", "Baxter", "Bandit", "Gus", "Samson", "Milo", "Rudy", "Louie", "Hunter", "Casey", "Rocco", "Sparky", "Joey", "Bruno", "Beau", "Dakota", "Maximus", "Romeo", "Boomer", "Luke", "Henry"]

female_names = ['Bella', 'Lucy', 'Molly', 'Daisy', 'Maggie', 'Sophie', 'Sadie', 'Chloe', 'Bailey', 'Lola', 'Zoe', 'Abby', 'Ginger', 'Roxy', 'Gracie', 'Coco', 'Sasha', 'Lily', 'Angel', 'Princess','Emma', 'Annie', 'Rosie', 'Ruby', 'Lady', 'Missy', 'Lilly', 'Mia', 'Katie', 'Zoey', 'Madison', 'Stella', 'Penny', 'Belle', 'Casey', 'Samantha', 'Holly', 'Lexi', 'Lulu', 'Brandy', 'Jasmine', 'Shelby', 'Sandy', 'Roxie', 'Pepper', 'Heidi', 'Luna', 'Dixie', 'Honey', 'Dakota']

puppy_images = ["http://pixabay.com/get/da0c8c7e4aa09ba3a353/1433170694/dog-785193_1280.jpg?direct", "http://pixabay.com/get/6540c0052781e8d21783/1433170742/dog-280332_1280.jpg?direct","http://pixabay.com/get/8f62ce526ed56cd16e57/1433170768/pug-690566_1280.jpg?direct","http://pixabay.com/get/be6ebb661e44f929e04e/1433170798/pet-423398_1280.jpg?direct","http://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2010/12/13/10/20/beagle-puppy-2681_640.jpg","http://pixabay.com/get/4b1799cb4e3f03684b69/1433170894/dog-589002_1280.jpg?direct","http://pixabay.com/get/3157a0395f9959b7a000/1433170921/puppy-384647_1280.jpg?direct","http://pixabay.com/get/2a11ff73f38324166ac6/1433170950/puppy-742620_1280.jpg?direct","http://pixabay.com/get/7dcd78e779f8110ca876/1433170979/dog-710013_1280.jpg?direct","http://pixabay.com/get/31d494632fa1c64a7225/1433171005/dog-668940_1280.jpg?direct"]

#This method will make a random age for each puppy between 0-18 months(approx.) old from the day the algorithm was run.
def CreateRandomAge():
    today = datetime.date.today()
    days_old = randint(0,540)
    birthday = today - datetime.timedelta(days = days_old)
    return birthday

#This method will create a random weight between 1.0-40.0 pounds (or whatever unit of measure you prefer)
def CreateRandomWeight():
    return random.uniform(1.0, 40.0)

for i,x in enumerate(male_names):
    new_puppy = Puppy(name = x, gender = "male", dateOfBirth = CreateRandomAge(),picture=random.choice(puppy_images) ,shelter_id=randint(1,5), weight= CreateRandomWeight())
    session.add(new_puppy)
    session.commit()

for i,x in enumerate(female_names):
    new_puppy = Puppy(name = x, gender = "female", dateOfBirth = CreateRandomAge(),picture=random.choice(puppy_images),shelter_id=randint(1,5), weight= CreateRandomWeight())
    session.add(new_puppy)
    session.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In neither the console example or the populator module are the database tables created (note also each engine definition has a different database name). When a non-existent table is queried, SQLite raises an error, like this*:

```
>>> import sqlalchemy as sa
>>>
>>> sqe = sa.create_engine('sqlite://')
>>> # Declare a table but don't create it.
>>> tb = sa.Table('t', sa.MetaData(), sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), primary_key=True))
>>> with sqe.connect() as conn:
...     res = conn.execute(sa.select(tb))
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: t
[SQL: SELECT t.id 
FROM t]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

The solution is to create the tables, like this if you are using the ORM:

```py
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

This must be done after the ORM model classes have been defined and before any queries are issued.

---

* This example uses SQLAlchemy core for brevity, but the error is the same whether the core or ORM layer is used.